# Discuss the "sorted" function in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I know the sorted() function in Python can operate on a number list or dictionaries, and it returns a list of sorted number or keys. For example:

```
w = [1,4,6,8,2,0,3,2]
sorted(w)
```

Then we can obtain the re-arranged sorted number list as [0,1,2,2,3,4,6,8]

My question is that: does sorted() function have any other functionality? I hope you guys could give me some simple examples. :)

Comment: did you checkout [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) ?

Comment: Yes, but sometimes I was confused about the words in the documentation. I want to see more examples.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python's `sorted` takes in any iterable (`list`, `dict`, `tuple`), e.g.,

```
>>> sorted([3,4,2,5]) # list
[2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> sorted({1: 'hello', 2: 'there', 4: 'foo', 3: 'bar'}) # dict
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> sorted(('Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz')) # tuple
```

Also, it can optionally take in a `key`, which means you can sort by some characteristic. For example, you could sort a string alphabetically or lexicographically:

```
>>> sorted(['hello', 'foo', 'bar'], key=str.lower)
['bar', 'foo', 'hello']
>>> sorted(['hello', 'foo', 'bar'], key=len)
['foo', 'bar', 'hello']
```

A cool feature of sorting using a given `key` means you can also provide a `lambda` expression, so, as in the following example, you can sort by the length of a dictionary value (list):

```
>>> x = { 1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 2: ['d'], 3: ['e', 'f'] }
>>> sorted( x, key=lambda k: len(x[k]) )
[2, 3, 1]
```

This also works with tuples:

```
>>> x = [('foo', 3, 2), ('bar', 1, 4), ('baz', 4, 1)]
>>> sorted(x, key=lambda k: k[1])
[('bar', 1, 4), ('foo', 3, 2), ('baz', 4, 1)]
```

Note that when sorting nested `list`s or `tuple`s (or other iterables), it will sort first by the first inner index and then by the subsequent inner indices.

You can also specify how you want to sort a class:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, name, age):
...         self.name = name
...         self.age = age
...     def __repr__(self): # this will help us recognize our objs after we've sorted
...         return "<name: {name}, age: {age}>".format(name=self.name, age=self.age)
>>> f = Foo('Bar', 3)
>>> g = Foo('Baz', 4)
>>> def byAge(foo): return foo.age
>>> sorted([f, g], key=byAge)
[<name: Bar, age: 3>, <name: Baz, age: 4>]
```

You can also use `attrgetter` to get an object's attribute to dictate what you want to sort on:

```
>>> from operator import attrgetter
>>> sorted([f, g], key=attrgetter('age'))
[<name: Bar, age: 3>, <name: Baz, age: 4>]
```

Furthermore, with `key`, you can have a function that combines multiple keys, e.g.,

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, name, age, years_programming):
...         self.name = name
...         self.age = age
...         self.years_programming = years_programming
...     def __repr__(self): # this will help us recognize our objs after we've sorted
...         return "<name: {name}, age: {age}, years_prog: {years}>".format(name=self.name, age=self.age, years=self.years_programming)
>>> f = Foo('Bar', 3, 1)
>>> g = Foo('Baz', 4, 3)
>>> h = Foo('John', 10, 0)
>>> def by_years_experience(foo):
...     return foo.age * foo.years_programming
>>> sorted([f, g, h], key=by_years_experience)
[<name: John, age: 10, years_prog: 0>, <name: Bar, age: 3, years_prog: 1>, <name: Baz, age: 4, years_prog: 3>]
```

Next, you can specify whether or not you want a reverse sort:

```
>>> sorted([3,4,7,2,1], reverse=True)
[7, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

`sorted` also works with lists of multiple types (only in Python 2):

```
>>> a = [('hello', 1, 2), ['foo', 5, 3], {0: 'bar', 1: 'baz'}]
>>> sorted(a)
[{0: 'bar', 1: 'baz'}, ['foo', 5, 3], ('hello', 1, 2)]
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[1])
[('hello', 1, 2), ['foo', 5, 3], {0: 'bar', 1: 'baz'}]
>>> b = ['hello', 1, 3]
>>> sorted(b)
[1, 3, 'hello']
```

Note: sorting among multiple types does *not* work in Python 3. You'll get a `TypeError`.

Lastly and for historical reasons, Python's `sorted` allows for a `cmp`, or comparison function. For example:

```
>>> def reverse_numeric(x, y):
...     return y - x
>>> sorted([3,4,7,2,1], cmp=reverse_numeric)
[7, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

It should be noted, too, that Python's `sorted` uses [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) as its sorting algorithm, which is a [stable sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts). This means that if there are multiple of the same element (or field), the original order will be preserved.

Sources:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted
- https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html
- https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting
- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/06/python-sorted/
- http://www.peterbe.com/plog/sorting-mixed-type-lists-in-python-3

Comment: Hope this helps -- I know documentation can be confusing at times or lacking examples, so hopefully this will give you a good (high-level) foundation going forward. :)

Comment: I do not know why somebody give me adverse score about my topic,  I just want to get some examples.